# Finding a minimal of the following variational problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> Let $X=\left\{f\in C^1[0,1]: f(0)=0=f(1)\right\}$.
>
> Define $J:X \to \Bbb R$ by $J(f)=\int\limits^1_0 \left(f^\prime (x)^2-4\pi^2 f(x)^2\right)dx.$
>
> Does $\inf\limits_{f\in X}J(f)$ exist?

If $F(x,f,f^\prime)=\left(f^\prime(x)^2-4\pi^2 f(x)^2\right)$, then to minimize $J(f)$, the function $F$ must satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation: $F_{f}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(F_{f^\prime}\right)=0$. Let me know how to approach this? I came to know that $\inf\limits_{f\in X}J(f)=-\infty$. How?

Edit: I have corrected the definition of $J(f)$.

Comment: I think you wrote the E-L equation wrong. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Lagrange_equation.. sorry the link points to wrong place

Comment: I think it should be $2 f - 8 \pi^2 f'' = 0$ which is solvable.

Comment: What happens with $J(f_n)$ for $f_n(t)=\sin(2\pi n t)$ when $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: @Gregory: $f \in C^1[0,1]$

Comment: Ok? I still don't see what that has to do with the form of the E-L equation

Comment: @Gregory: The condition $F_x+\frac{d}{dx}(f^\prime F_{f^\prime}-F)= 0$ can be obtained from The E-L equation if $f^{\prime\prime}$ exists.

Comment: @ A.Γ. : I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=n\sin(\pi x)$. Then
$$
J(f_n)=\int_0^1(n^2\pi^2\cos^2(\pi x)-4\pi^2n^2\sin^2(\pi x))\,dx=-\frac{3\pi^2}{2}n^2\to -\infty,\quad n\to+\infty
$$

Comment: Though I agree this is correct, how would one arrive at this without guessing? What if the boundary conditions didn't necessarily admit an obvious guess?

Comment: @Gregory Yeah, some kind of guessing is always necessary in counter-examples, but here trial and error is quite intuitively obvious. I think even a simple triangle shape like $f(x)=x$ first and $1-x$ at the end may work here, since the coefficient $4\pi^2$ is large. Once you found a function with negative $J$ the rest is just to amplify it because $J$ is homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

The E-L equation yields $f'' + 4 \pi^2 f = 0$. The result is $f(x) = A \sin (2\pi x) + B \cos (2 \pi x)$. The boundary conditions imply $f(x) = A \sin (2\pi x)$. Plugging this into $J$
\begin{align*}
J(f) & = 4 \pi ^2 A^2 \int_0^1 \cos^2(2 \pi x ) - \sin^2(2\pi x) \ dx \\
& = 4 \pi^2 A \int_0^1 \cos(4\pi x) \ dx \\
& = \pi A \sin (4\pi x) \big|_0^1 \\
& = 0.
\end{align*}
The minimum of the function should be 0. In fact if we try the Ansatz $f_n = \sin (2 \pi n x)$ we also see that it takes a minimum value at $0$.

Comment: But $f\in C^1[0,1]$, how do I know that $f^{\prime\prime}$ exists?