# Find possible extrema of the functional $J(u)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{u'(x)^2-4u(x)^2dx}$

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

> Let $u$ be a continous differentiable function with support in $\left[0,2\pi \right]$ and
> $$J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{u'(x)^2-4u(x)^2dx}$$
> What are the possible extrema for $J$ ?

I first computed the first variation which is

$$
\partial J(u,\phi) =-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\phi(x) \cdot \left( u''(x)+4u(x) \right)dx}
$$

Functions solving $\partial J(u,\phi) =0$ gives rise to the differential equation

$$u''=-4u$$

$\implies$
$$u(x)=c_1sin(2x)+c_1cos(2x)$$

I then computed the second variation $$\partial^2 J(u,\phi) =\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\phi'(x)^2-4\phi(x)^2 dx}$$

However, I do not know if $\partial^2 J(u,\phi) \ge 0$ or $\partial^2 J(u,\phi) \le 0$ holds for every $\phi$

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you thought about the case where $\phi$ is constant?

Comment: @user159517 I edited my question. I am looking for possible extrema (minimum or maximum). In the case for $\phi =const$ it would be $\le 0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a minimal of the following variational problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829762/finding-a-minimal-of-the-following-variational-problem) ; reference found using the efficient formula searching engine approach0.xyz